# Mongoose multiple documents of same schema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Noob question but how do I create multiple documents of the same schema without having to declare a new const. Do I need to create an array for each key e.g

```
const newItem = new Item({
  name: ["Blue Shirt", "Green Shirt"],
  image: ["images/image-1.jpg","images/image-2.jpg"],
  price: [30, 20],
  quantity: [5, 10]
});
```

<------------Orginal Code ------------->

```
const newItem = new Item({
  name: "Blue Shirt",
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300",
  price: 30,
  quantity: 5
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an array of your data.

```
const newItem = new Item({
  name: "Blue Shirt",
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300",
  price: 30,
  quantity: 5
});

var arr = [newItem]; //Pass array of documents / objects.
Item.insertMany(arr, function(error, docs) {});
```

Or

```
var arr = ['{
  name: "Blue Shirt",
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300",
  price: 30,
  quantity: 5
}', {
  name: "Blue Shirt",
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300",
  price: 30,
  quantity: 5
}]; //Pass array of documents / objects.

Item.insertMany(arr, function(error, docs) {});
```

You can explore more on https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany